# trying to store time into array using chrono

Tags: c++, arrays, time, c++-chrono

I am measuring the time of an algorithm I wrote, and using std::chrono to measure it in microseconds. However, I am also trying to store these elapsed values into an array, and I'm not sure how. I tried this (my array is of type int)

```
 std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);


 time_insertion_sort[i][j] = elapsed;
```

and I get the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l,
       1000000l> >' to 'int' in assignment

time_insertion_sort[i][j] = elapsed;
```

I thought maybe it would work if I declared my array as a type long, but it still doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You probably just want to add `.count()` to the end of the duration cast.  You might try making your question more complete so we can see the context.

Comment: If you want to find out how much time is required to execute a function or particular piece of code use a profile. Using `std::chrono` does not take into account task switching other other considerations that may skew your results.

Comment: and thanks to everyone for downvoting without saying why, as is usually the case here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state your array is of type `int` and the error is saying it cannot convert the `std::duration` type to `int`. Therefore you need to get the *raw* value and store it or store `std::duration` type in your array.

```
auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);

// You should be able to store this raw value.
auto rawValue = elapsed.count();
```

**Note**, the type returned by the `count` function is the representation type of the `std::duration`. Your error message indicates the representation type is `long int` and as such you are subject to overflow if `sizeof(int)` is not the same as `sizeof(long)`.